# subgit - svn's trunk and root folder to be combined in git's master folder

Tags: git, svn, subgit

Below is my svn repository structure

svnrepo

- trunk
- branches
- tags
- folder1
- folder2

I want to have `trunk` content, `folder1` and `folder2` in git repositories `master` branch, how can I achieve this using `subgit` migration?

gitrepo (master)

- trunk content
- folder1
- folder2

Comment: There are many `svn2git` tools out there. Do you use the proper one, the one the KDE guys created that is found at https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git and described in the description of the `svn2git` tag or some other like the nirvdrum `svn2git` that is based on `git-svn` and thus not really suited for producing good migration results?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you don't want branches/ and tags/ in Git. In this case you can use the following configuration:

```
trunk = trunk:refs/heads/master
branches = folder1:refs/heads/folder1
branches = folder2:refs/heads/folder2
```

You can find more information about trunk/branches/tags/shelves options in [branches mapping](https://subgit.com/branches-mapping.html) article. Optionally you can add `shelves=shelves/*:refs/shelves/*` option if you need bi-directional translation and want to translate every single Git commit to a separate revision in case of self-merges in branches.

**Update**: the question was about translating trunk and a couple of branches into the same Git branch. I can only propose the following approach:

```
trunk = :refs/heads/master
includePath = /trunk
includePath = /folder1
includePath = /folder2
```

It will translate the project root into refs/heads/master but skip everything except these 3 directories. Note that not skipped directories will still be downloaded from SVN but discarded locally later.

This this is the closest solution to your original question, I don't know anything better.

Comment: Sorry for misinterpretation. tags and branches are also required, but trunk content, folder1 and folder2 should go to master branch. As per your solution, 2 new branches will be created. Do you mean, after branches are created merge them to master?